# UDF Methods For Determining Currency or Double

Tags: vb.net, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-dna

I'm creating a `UDF` in `VB.NET` that sometimes works with `currency`, which I would need to use the `Decimal` format in `VB`. But sometimes I working with `time` or just a plain `double`. What methods are out their for determining how I should add the values up, with a `decimal` or `double`?

I prefer not to have excel return the actual range for simplicity sake but will do if I need to determine if it is formatted as currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Excel uses Doubles for currency, time values, integers and all other numbers its not usually neccessary to find out how the number is formatted for Excel display purposes: just add the values up.= as doubles.

Comment: But if I add them as `doubles` won't the accuracy be off for the total when adding up `currency` values? That's my main concern. I'm using the `UDF` to add `time` values (which is OK with `double`), but also use it to add up `currency` and I thought the recommendation was that you use `Decimal` type variable for that.

Comment: If you want to add Excel values in the same way that Excel does you have to use doubles because thats how Excel stores and calculates them (IEE Floating point doubles)

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that that is how Excel always adds them up. Thanks for the help! So, I suppose excel isn't the best for adding up finances then since it doesn't use `Decimal` type variable? I guess that's a new question :)